# Changing viewport anti-aliasing through code

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a script to help me optimize my viewport for better performance.
One way is changing the viewport aa. I have already found the line of code in which I can reference aa:

```
import bpy

bpy.types.PreferencesSystem.viewport_aa
```

But I can't figure out how to set a variable. My best guess was:

```
import bpy

bpy.types.PreferencesSystem.viewport_aa = "FXAA"
```

When I run that script, I don't get an error but nothing happens either. It's probably something simple I'm missing.

Thanks in advance!

If it helps: [Blender API help link](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.93/bpy.types.PreferencesSystem.html?highlight=preferencessystem%20viewport_aa#bpy.types.PreferencesSystem.viewport_aa)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is accessed through the ever intuitive  [`bpy.context.preferences.system.viewport_aa`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PreferencesSystem.html#bpy.types.PreferencesSystem.viewport_aa)

You should be able to write directly to this variable:

`bpy.context.preferences.system.viewport_aa = 'OFF'`

for example.

Comment: This worked, thanks! Unfortunately it looks like I'll have to order a set of keycaps, ctrl, c and v are already starting to wear down...